# Is java char big endian in JVM memory?

Tags: java, jvm, endianness

Is java char big endian in JVM memory [stack/heap]? That is is it UTF-16 LE or UTF-16 BE?

I think It really shouldn't matter that much and it is upto JVM implementation and keeps the native chip order for perf. reasons. That is LE for intel etc. Is that correct?

Or is it specified in Java spec. itself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Java, the language, is endianness-agnostic. (The JVM implementation probably uses the hardware endianness.)

Varying ways of converting characters to a byte sequence have fixed endiannesses, though, e.g. [`DataOutputStream`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/DataOutputStream.html#writeChar%28int%29).

Comment: Thanks - do we know for sure that JVMs [atleast the common ones like hotspot] always use hardware endianness or simply use BE?

Comment: Why does it matter?  You can't tell, from the outside.

Comment: Just curious and why they made that decision [particularly if it is the latter, always BE]?

Comment: Printing compiled assembly has always made it look to me like it was using hardware endianness.  Eh.  It's not specified, it might change in future releases.

Comment: @Louis Wasserman - you may not be able to tell from the outside, but I can.

Answer (score 7):

The class file format specifies that all items must be in big-endian.
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-4.html

I haven't checked but I suspect JNI spec also talks about the endian-ness and I suspect it is in big-endian.

Comment: It's somewhat old already, but to prevent confusion for everybody reading this and Joachim Sauer's answer: The link given here specifies the endianess in the (platform-agnostic) .class file format - not the in memory structure of primitive datatypes. I have not read the full spec, but I assume others are right and it is not specified but any/most JVM will use platform endianess in memory. NI's LabView is the only thing I have yet seen that does crazy things like using big endian encoded values on a little endian system.

Answer (score 0):

It's not specified by the VM spec and is up to the VM how to handle it.

And since there's no direct way to re-interpret `char` as two `byte` values you can't even see the result of the decision from a Java program (any Java application will act exactly the same on a conforming VM, independent of the endianness of the VM).

Comment: JNI can see it.  The J stands for Java IIRC.

Answer (score 0):

A single char is either little-endian or big-endian based on your processor's hardware. Most Intel/AMD/ARM processors use little-endian and Sparc/Alpha use big-endian.

The UTF-16 encoding is how Java stores codepoints (characters up to 0x1FFFF) in Strings. The UTF-16LE encoding refers to how such a string can be written to a file.

Comment: Char is not a concept known to processor. It is Java which imposes some 'meaning' to 2 bytes. UTF-16LE means something even if you have only 2 bytes.

Comment: A `char` is an unsigned short and every processor supports this type. Treating it as two bytes would be very inefficient.

Comment: But most of the processors nowadays are 64 or 32 bit. So even short is as inefficient as byte!

Comment: The processor being 32-bit or 64-bit usually refers to the maximum size of an address not the data. Even 32-bit processors can do 64-bit and 128-bit operations e.g. SSE2 operations are 128-bit on a "32-bit" processor.  An unsigned short is the most efficient type for a `char` regardless for the bit-ness of the processor.

Comment: I didn't mean the address part. 64 bit processor assumes 64 bit data as 'atomic' unit. So it is the easiest unit for the processor to work with. For anything else it has to do bit chopping in registers. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/64-bit "Without further qualification, a 64-bit computer architecture generally has integer and addressing registers that are 64 bits wide, allowing direct support for 64-bit data types and addresses."

Comment: 32-bit x86 intel/AMD processors support 8-bit, 16-bit, 32-bit, 64-bit, 80-bit (floating point) and 128-bit (SSE2) values in a single register. It supports 32-bit addresses. The 64-bit x64 supports more 64-bit registers and 64-bit address space (technically they are limited to 48-bit).  In any case they all support 16-bit values and when a `char` is used, these are the operations it uses.

Comment: The wikipedia quote is slightly misleading IMHO. The bitness of a CPU is determined entirely by the size of a pointer. IF the size of data that the cpu can work directly with determined the bitness, then the first Pentium could be called an 80-bit processor, since it has 80-bit FPU registers. Which it isn't, it's 32-bit, because the range of a pointer in a Pentium is 32 bits.

Comment: The size of the data bus is also irrelevant. The Pentium had a 64-bit data bus. It was 64-bits mostly for memory bandwidth, and it even had a cmpxchg8b (64-bit atomic compare and swap) instruction. Still 32-bit.

Comment: @doug65536 The 8087 had 80-bit FP (used to have one ;) Even though the Pentium had 32-bit pointers it also support segments which gives another 16-bits.

Comment: I don't want to get too much discussion going in comments but agreed, as far as bits go, the Pentium is all over the place! ;-)